# Storing ZIP codes as 1, 2, or 3 fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, street-address

I've read about ZIPs and know that I should store them as a char or varchar. I'm primarily concerned about US Zips in standard 5 digit and the +4 extension, but will acknowledge there may be a need for Canadian codes as well. Sometimes I will know the full 5+4 zip, sometimes I will only know the 5 digit. I'm concerned about speed but also data integrity. I don't care about harddrive space. Here's my options:

Should I use:
(1) a single varchar(10) field to store the whole string?
(2) a char(5), plus a varchar(4) for the optional +4 extension
(3) a varchar(10) + char(5)
(4) a varchar(10) + char(5) + varchar(4)

I believe there are pros/cons to each method when balancing query speed but maybe I'm overestimating the differences. I *assume* that performing a regex on the varchar(10) will be slower than matching the char(5) - which is what I would be doing 99% of the time. That is why I'm wanting a char(5) field, but still need somewhere to store the full zip when I have it.

**I'm leaning towards option 3** because the varchar(10) gives me flexibility for storing all international codes and the char(5) field would be useful for 99% of the queries that I do. I will just have to be careful with my POST scripts and SQL to always update both fields to maintain integrity. If it makes any difference, my current engine is InnoDB for a 23MB table with 117 columns and 13,000 rows that I expect to double in size. I know it's not big but I'm interested in setting this up in the best way.

Comment: Do you really need to distinguish between ZIP and ZIP+4 in your application? Or just store them as opaque strings?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? You mention T-SQL, which is the SQL dialect used with SQL-Server.

Comment: Don't be too precise about this. The Post Office cares about ZIP codes being correct. You don't. Just allow some number of characters, and don't validate.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I didn't realise TSQL is unique to SQL-Server. I am using MySQL. 
There are times where I need to output the full zip when shipping items, but others when I will only want the first 5 digits (running reports, searching)